# Extra Buttons on SharePoint 2013 NewForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a site, when the user completes viewing items on the site,  they click a complete button (that was hidden until they completed the required tasks) that pops up a NewForm for the attendance list. Once the user adds their name and clicks save, the NewForm should close.  I created a NewForm (NewForm_CloseAfter.aspx) and pointed the site to open the NewForm_CloseAfter.aspx (no problems so far).

See code below.  I commented out the SharePoint button and added the html input button.

The problem:  My html input button at the bottom of the form works fine.  However, looks like the default save/cancel button is at the top with the default behavior of submitting the information and showing the list (unwanted behavior)

The Question: How can I remove the default buttons at the top of my form?

Thanks

```html
<tr>
   <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td width="99%" class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap"><IMG SRC="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="1" height="18"/></td>
      <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
       <!--<SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="savebutton2"/>-->
       <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Save" id="savebutton2" style="width:75px" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit')}; window.alert('Item updated.') ; window.close();"  />
      </td>
      <td class="ms-separator">&#160;</td>
      <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
       <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="gobackbutton2"/>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the your custom new form in designer and search for "savebutton1". Find the surrounding tr and comment out it and you are done.